# Limits of BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, boost-fusion

I have tried to play with the `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` macro and tried some naive things such as use Fusion to print any arbitrary structure.

Starting from this [example code given in the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html), I was unable to perform on my adapted structure some operations that are allowed with a fusion sequence.

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/sequence/io/out.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/sequence/intrinsic.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/view.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace fuz = boost::fusion;

namespace demo
{
    struct employee
    {
        std::string name;
        int age;
    };
}

// demo::employee is now a Fusion sequence
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    demo::employee,
    (std::string, name)
    (int, age))

int main()
{
    // tried to initialize an employee like a fusion sequence
    // but it didnt work
    // demo::employee e("bob", 42);

    demo::employee e;
    e.name = "bob";
    e.age = 42;

    // Access struct members with fusion random access functions
    // ok
    std::cout << fuz::at_c<0>(e) << std::endl; 

    // tried to print the struct like any othe fusion sequence
    // didnt work
    // std::cout << e << std::endl;

    // I made it work by using a fusion view
    // is it the right way?
    std::cout << fuz::as_nview<0, 1>(e) << std::endl;
}
```

This leads me to the following questions :

- Why the Fusion magik does not operate here?
- Using a view is the correct way to print an adapted struct?
- How far can an adapted struct be used as a Fusion sequence?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the `boost::fusion` documentation:

> The I/O operators are overloaded in namespace boost::fusion

Which means that if you want a implicit integration of these `operator<<`, you will need to inject the `boost::fusion` namespace in your current namespace (`::` here), or use them explicitly.

To sum it all up, adding:

```
using namespace boost::fusion;
```

Should work in your case.
Or for an explicit use, you will have to write:

```
boost::fusion::operator<<(std::cout, e) << std::endl;
```

**--- EDIT ---**

After reading `boost::fusion`'s code a bit, it seem that you are confused because of the **Koenig's lookup** of `boost::fusion::operators::operator<<` which is selected in case your argument is a real `boost::fusion::sequence`.

This is why you don't need to inject the `boost::fusion` namespace, nor explicitly call `boost::fusion::operator<<` for types defined in the `boost::fusion` namespace.

Some explanations:

I won't explain the whole concept of Koenig's lookup (also known as [Argument Dependent Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) - ADL) here since that is not the point, but basically, it states that in case you are using a variable whose type is inside a namespace, then the function lookup extends to the namespace of that parameter.

In this particular case, including `boost/fusion/sequence/io/out.hpp` will define `boost::fusion::operator::operator<<` which will then be injected in the `boost::fusion` namespace.

```
$ cat /usr/local/include/boost/fusion/sequence/io/out.hpp
[...]
namespace boost { namespace fusion
{
    [...]
    namespace operators
    {
        template <typename Sequence>
        inline typename
            boost::enable_if<
               fusion::traits::is_sequence<Sequence>
              , std::ostream&
            >::type // this is just a SFINAE trick to ensure
                    // the function will only be selected for
                    // actual boost::fusion::sequence
        operator<<(std::ostream& os, Sequence const& seq)
        {
            return fusion::out(os, seq); // this will print out the sequence
        }
    }
    using operators::operator<<; // here the operator<< is injected
                                 // in boost::fusion
}}
```

**This means that calls using** `operator<<` **with parameters whose types are in the** `boost::fusion` **namespace will find the proper overload.**

Calls using arguments whose type is not located in this namespace will fail to resolve the proper overload of `operator<<` (this is the case in your example).

You can check that by defining your type in the `boost::fusion` namespace.

```
namespace boost { namespace fusion {
struct employee
{
  std::string name;
  int age;
};
}}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    boost::fusion::employee,
    (std::string, name)
    (int, age))

[...]
boost::fusion::employee e;
std::cout << e << std::endl; // ADL will work here
```

Side note: If you want to debug these kind of name lookup issues, you should use `gdb`. That way you will always know which overload was chosen. In this case:

```
$ cat fusion.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <boost/fusion/container/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/sequence/io.hpp>

int main(int, char**)
{
  boost::fusion::vector<int, char> foo(42, '?');
  std::cout << foo << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

$ gdb -q ./fusion
Reading symbols for shared libraries ... done
(gdb) b 10
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1000012f7: file fusion.cpp, line 10.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /Users/avallee/Projects/tmp/fusion
Reading symbols for shared libraries ++............................. done

Breakpoint 1, main (unnamed_arg=0x7fff5fbffb60, unnamed_arg=0x7fff5fbffb60) at fusion.cpp:10
10    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
(gdb) s
boost::fusion::operators::operator<< <boost::fusion::vector<int, char, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> > (os=@0x7fff762b5f10, seq=@0x7fff5fbffb18) at out.hpp:38
38              return fusion::out(os, seq);
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks a lot Aurelien for your great detailed explanation. I've also found [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/boost-list/8advI2HoqF8/nUF7uL4PtSwJ) on google groups. As your explanation would lead to, the simplest way to get things working is put this in the demo namespace :

```
namespace demo{
    using boost::fusion::operators::operator<<;
    ...
```