# recursive tuple -- list using tuples instead of structs

Tags: c++, tuples

Is it possible to make a list out tuple?

```
typedef std::tuple<int,node*> node;
```

A run-time equivalent would be:

```
struct node {
  int i; 
  node* next
};
```

**Update (1)**

Since I got a lot of criticism. I'll expand on the question. Originally I just wanted to keep it simple.

(1) I prefer using tuples to structs. one of the reasons is that I use boost fusion for io, algorithms and meta-programming. structs don't have that. for more information on tuples or an equivalent boost::fusion::vector, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/quick_start.html

(2) Specifically, I use a number of structures similar to this one:

```
struct SLseg{
    int      edge;         
    Point    lP;           
    Point    rP;          
    SLseg*   above;         
    SLseg*   below;        
};
```

I don't want to write `operator<<` for each one of them or use inheritance. [boost::fusion's io](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/sequence/operator/i_o.html) and [pretty-print](http://louisdx.github.io/cxx-prettyprint/) provide facilities to output the structures given that they are tuples; even if there are stl containers in the tuples.

(3) list is just a simple example. think of having a heterogeneous list where the type is determined using `enable_if` with some fusion/mpl algorithms.

Comment: Umm... yes? `std::vector<std::tuple<int, node*> >`?

Comment: I'm sure I misunderstand the question, though. So could you please elaborate/clarify?

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with `boost` or `recursion`?

Comment: @Jashaszun I think the problem is that `node` isn't in scope yet at the point of `std::tuple<int,node*>`, so you can't use `node *` as a template parameter...

Comment: what would be the point of the construct? It's the same as the "runtime equivalent", both layout are available compile time.

Comment: @T.C. What do you mean ? `node` could just be forward declared in that case ?

Comment: @quantdev The code attempts to make `node` an alias of `std::tuple<int, node*>`. You can't forward declare a typedef.

Comment: @T.C. got it, didnt see that in the first read

Comment: Perhaps `struct node : std::tuple<int, node*> { using tuple::tuple; };`

Comment: @T.C. is correct. `node` is not in the scope.

Comment: I don't get whats wrong with `std::list<int>` (or `vector`)

Comment: @quantdev how would you define `node` as a `tuple`?

Comment: Your "runtime equivalent" is simply a linked list of integers, why would you need tuples for this ?

Comment: @Jashaszun boost has mpl and fusion. they work with type. they might have utilities to deal with recursion inside typedef.

Comment: @quantdev, list is just a simple example. there are more complicated structure that would benefit from fusion algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

While not a real solution, you can still turn a `struct` into a Fusion sequence with [FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html). Also note [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241932/limits-of-boost-fusion-adapt-struct) which shows how to properly integrate IO with such an adapted struct.